# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.4.1:wsimport

Tags: java, spring, maven, webservice-client, wsimport

I am getting an error while I was generating code by jaxws wsimport plugin in my Java project.

I have tried every way in pom.xml file but I could not compile successfully. I got the error where is in the title.

I might give some details more about that I have tried until now.

Is there anyone encounter with this compilation error?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>test</name>
    <description>test</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-boot-admin.version>2.1.3</spring-boot- 
   admin.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-admin.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web- 
    services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Needed to run the plugin xjc en Java 8 or 
    superior -->
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>set-additional-system-properties</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            
    <name>javax.xml.accessExternalSchema</name>
                            <value>all</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            
    <name>javax.xml.accessExternalDTD</name>
                            <value>all</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                    <outputFile/>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                
    <source>$${project.basedir}/src/main/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>testws</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>

                        <configuration>
                            
    <wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdller</wsdlDirectory>
                            <wsdlFiles>
                                <wsdlFile>Test.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                            </wsdlFiles>
                            
    <packageName>com.test.wsdl</packageName>
                            <vmArgs>
                                <vmArg>- 
   Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
                            </vmArgs>
                            <keep>true</keep>
                            
    <sourceDestDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    </project>
```

Comment: Could you add `POM` in your question, please? It'll be more informative.

Comment: I have shared a part of my pom.xml file. I got the error when I have put this part into executions.

Comment: Please, refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). To reproduce your issue needs more details. Also, probably, similar error was [here](https://github.com/mojohaus/jaxws-maven-plugin/issues/56).